# Sequential method calls within a single Task vs ContinueWith for each method call

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I came across this snippet of code the other day:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    d1();
}).ContinueWith((_) =>
{
    d2();
}).ContinueWith((_) =>
{
    d3();
});
```

Are there any reasons why I couldn't just refactor this to the below?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    d1();
    d2();
    d3();
});
```

Comment: What is the question?!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask: *your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”*

Comment: question: "why not just", seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Ouch... lost all repuation on 1 question.

Comment: The thing is that this is at its base a valid question, it's just worded so poorly and rantingly that no one will take it seriously.

Comment: @Rotem Well, almost no one.  ;)

Comment: There's always @Servy.

Comment: @sam Your edit seems to change the semantics of what the question is asking.  The original revision was basically asking "what's the difference between these two", now it is asking, "what's the point of ContinueWith", which is a much broader question.

Comment: @Servy It looked to me like the question was `is this Task.ContinueWith a joke`? which I read as `Why would anyone want to use Task.ContinueWith`

Comment: Thanks to the editors for removing the ranty nature of the question. I've retracted my downvote and close vote.

Comment: @Servy - I've edited (rewritten) the question body.  Perhaps a new title is required now?

Comment: @SamIam As my answer indicates, I interpreted it much as MattC's edit does.  Most people understand the usefulness of a `ContinueWith` call to a task that was created in another scope, or that has different arguments (i.e. another task scheduler), but I have seen people write code with continuations of tasks defined int he same scope, much like the first code snippet.  It's a legitimate question to inquire about the semantics of that particular narrow usage of `ContinueWith`, and it makes sense to consider refactoring it as is done in the second code sample.

Comment: @Servy Now I've written the question I feel I should be allowed to accept your proposed answer as the accepted one! lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, they don't behave identically, even if the author intended them to.

Let's assume that `d1` is implemented like so:

```
public static void d1(){throw new Exception();}
```

In the first code snippet `d2` and `d3` both run (because the continuations, by default, will execute even if the task they are a continuation of faults; they could be configured to act otherwise of course).  In the second, they don't, as the exception in the first method call propagates out, skipping execution of the other two methods.

So anytime you see the first code, you cannot immediately refactor it to the second.  (However you may very well ask yourself if you should; it's possible the author intended to have the semantics of the second, even if they wrote the first.)

Comment: thank, you make me learn more about it.  i think many one do not know that. is my question benefit for you?

Comment: @awint23, don't mind buddy! But this is a QnA site, you need to learn these codes from their own sites, such as msdn.microsoft.com